# How to modify population within for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, anylogic, population

I have a for-loop to iterate over my population. For a condition, I want to remove that object from my population. When I run my model, a `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs. The reason should be, that I cannot modify my population, while iterating over the collection in a for-loop.

Is there any simple way to fix that problem?
I tried using an iterator, but because my code is in an event, which occurs every minute new, it did not really work.

```
for (testpop t : testpops) {
    if (dateToTime(t.arrival) <= time()) {
        System.out.println(t.arrival);
        remove_testpops(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop over a copy of `testpops` (e.g. `for testpop t : new ArrayList(testpops)) ...`, or use an iterator to iterate and use its remove method. I'm not sure why _"because my code is in an event, which occurs every minute new"_ would be a reason that an iterator wouldn't work.

Comment: you should probably use an iterator which offers remove.